# Manage sitemaps for multiple sites in Google Search Console

Tags: sitemap, xml-sitemap, sitemap-index

We are dynamically generating `sitemap.xml` files and hosting them on content delivery network (CDN) which is not on our primary web site domain.

Primary website: `https://bla.example/sitemap-index.xml` < sitemap index file hosted on the primary website domain, i.e. our website.

CDN: `https://cdn.example/sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml` < sitemap files hosted on the CDN that have URLs which point back to the primary website.

Examples:

`https://bla.example/sitemap-index.xml`

```
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     <sitemap>
          <loc>https://cdn.example/sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml</loc>
          <lastmod>2022-05-23T21:00:00+00:00</lastmod>
     </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

`https://cdn.example/sitemaps/sitemap-1.xml`

```
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
     <url>
          <loc>https://bla.example/</loc>
          <lastmod>2018-06-04</lastmod>
     </url>
</urlset>
```

**Problem**

I have followed [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/sitemaps/large-sitemaps?visit_id=637913620966361282-3383997486&rd=1) and verified both `https://bla.example` and `https://cdn.example/sitemaps` in Google Search Console but `sitemap-index.xml` (on the primary domain) has a status of "Couldn't fetch" after a week or so.

I have verified the `sitemap-index.xml` and `sitemap.xml` files in a XML sitemap validator.

I have used the "check any URL" tool in Google Search Console to verify Google can hit both files and the sitemaps are returned.

I have tested adding a regular `sitemap.xml` to the primary domain (`https://bla.example/sitemap.xml`) and Google Search Console has successfully discovered that file.

Comment: Google's documentation for cross-domain sitemaps: https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2007/10/dealing-with-sitemap-cross-submissions  Have you verified the cdn hostname in Google Search Console?

Comment: Yes, https://cdn.example/sitemaps has been verified in Google Search Console.